# Continuously running task: write output cached?

Tags: bash, unix, raspberry-pi

I have a continuously running task on my Raspberry Pi which returns one line of text about every second. I append it to log.txt with

```
command >> log.txt
```

Now this log.txt is only updated in batches, about every 5 minutes. How can I fix that it updates with every new line that is appended, thus every second?

Comment: Presumably your raspi has access to a build of `expect`?  http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/25375/516

Comment: `stdbuf  -oL -eL command >> log.txt`?

Comment: sudo stdbuf -oL <command> >> file.txt did the trick! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If your `command` uses `printf` or other C-library functions instead of the raw `write` syscall, the output is always buffered within the program.

If the output goes to a terminal, it's line buffered, so it writes after each `\n`.

But if it goes into a file or pipe, the buffer will be much larger, probably an entire page like 4096 bytes. Can you change the code of `command`?

Comment: I think you're right, I fixed my issue with Blue Moon's suggestion of making the buffer smaller

Answer (score 0):

If you are programming in C: close the filehandle and open it after any line.
Don't expect a good performance.

In some cases commands uses output buffering, if the file pointer is not connected to a terminal.

```
command | while IFS='' read -r in; do
    echo "$in" >> log.txt
done
```

It is only a guess, but writing to a pipe may turn the buffering off.
Can you turn buffering off in the configuration of your program?